# SQL statement has view wrong

Tags: sql

I have this SQL statement on making a view which is....

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwPlayersBatting]
AS
    SELECT        
        dbo.Players.playerIDpk, dbo.Players.birthDate, 
        dbo.Players.birthCountry, dbo.Players.birthState, 
        dbo.Players.birthCity, dbo.Players.deathDate, 
        dbo.Players.deathCountry, dbo.Players.deathState, 
        dbo.Players.deathCity, dbo.Players.nameFirst, 
        dbo.Players.nameLast, dbo.Players.nameGiven, 
        dbo.Players.weight, dbo.Players.height, 
        dbo.Players.bats, dbo.Players.throws, 
        dbo.Players.debutDate, dbo.Players.finalGameDate, 
        dbo.Batting.BattingIDPK, dbo.Batting.yearID, 
        dbo.Batting.stint, dbo.Batting.lgID, dbo.Batting.G, 
        dbo.Batting.AB, dbo.Batting.R, dbo.Batting.H, dbo.Batting.B2, 
        dbo.Batting.B3, dbo.Batting.HR, dbo.Batting.RBI, dbo.Batting.SB, 
        dbo.Batting.CS, dbo.Batting.BB, dbo.Batting.SO, dbo.Batting.IBB, 
        dbo.Batting.HBP, dbo.Batting.SH, dbo.Batting.SF, dbo.Batting.GIDP, 
        dbo.Batting.teamID, 
        (dbo.Batting.H - dbo.Batting.B2 - dbo.Batting.B3 - dbo.Batting.HR) AS S,
        (((dbo.Batting.H - dbo.Batting.B2 - dbo.Batting.B3 - dbo.Batting.HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR *4)) AS 'TB', 
        H*1.0/(Case when AB=0 then 1 else AB end) AS 'BA',
        (Case when (H + BB + HBP) = 0 then 1.0 else ((H + BB + HBP)*1.0) end) / (Case when (AB + BB + HBP) = 0 then 1.0 else ((AB + BB + HBP)*1.0) end) AS 'OBP',
        (Case when (((dbo.Batting.H - dbo.Batting.B2 - dbo.Batting.B3 - dbo.Batting.HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR *4)) = 0 then 1 else (((dbo.Batting.H - dbo.Batting.B2 - dbo.Batting.B3 - dbo.Batting.HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR *4)) end)/(Case when AB=0 then 1 else AB end) AS 'SLG',
        (Case when (H + BB + HBP) = 0 then 1.0 else ((H + BB + HBP)*1.0) end) / (Case when (AB + BB + HBP) = 0 then 1.0 else ((AB + BB + HBP)*1.0) end) + (Case when (((dbo.Batting.H - dbo.Batting.B2 - dbo.Batting.B3 - dbo.Batting.HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR *4)) = 0 then 1 else (((dbo.Batting.H - dbo.Batting.B2 - dbo.Batting.B3 - dbo.Batting.HR) * 1.0) + (B2 * 2) + (B3 * 3) + (HR *4)) end)/(Case when AB=0 then 1 else AB end) AS 'OPS' 
    FROM            
        dbo.Players 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Batting ON dbo.Players.playerIDpk = dbo.Batting.playerID
```

I have it all in formulas to keep it from having a divide by zero error, however it changes the .000 columns to a 1.0000, I also can't figure out how to round the columns using that to 3 decimal places, so instead of .261904 I'll have just .262, I believe the math error has somewhat to do with not rounding them up or down before doing the math..

The column for OBP and SLG are incorrect because the math doesn't add up and if the player has a 000 for his OBP or SLG it automatically makes it a 1.0 and than my OPS column turns it into a 1.0 right away and I'm not sure how I can correct that or if I'm making it to complex and I don't need all of that.. here is what the columns are supposed to have for their math..

For SLG it is

Total Bases divided by At-Bats. or (TB) / (AB)

For OBP it is

a) Hits (H + Walks (BB) + Times Hit by Pitch (HBP) (This sum is the total Times on Base)

(b) Calculate Total Plate Appearances by adding At Bats (AB), Walks (BB) and times Hit by Pitch (HBP)

(c) Then divide sum (a)  into (b) (Total Plate Appearances

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: What prevents you from just loading DB records as is, and doing all the branchy math calculations in the app layer, using a more convenient language?

Comment: nevermind on this, I figured it all out